# CollabNet Subversion Edge Ignore Files

Tags: php, eclipse, actionscript-3, svn, subversion-edge

I am brand new at sub-versioning, so please bear with me.

I use CollabNet's Subversion Edge to manage a repository for a PHP/ActionScript based project I am building in the Eclipse IDE. In my project's root folder, Eclipse included several configuration files that aren't directly related to the project. How can I set up my repository to ignore these files/folders via CollabNet? Would it be through the "Repository Access Rules"?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[Chapter 3. Advanced Topics 'Ignoring Unversioned Items'](http://www.collab.net/community/subversion/svnbook/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)" seems appropriate for your setup:

Extract:

> [...] But these not-to-be-versioned files and directories can cause some annoyance for Subversion users.
>   For example, because the `svn add` and `svn import` commands act recursively by default, and don't know which files in a given tree you do and don't wish to version, it's easy to accidentally add stuff to version control that you didn't mean to.
>   And because `svn status` reports, by default, every item of interest in a working copy–including unversioned files and directories–its output can get quite noisy where many of these things exist.
>
> So Subversion provides two ways for telling it which files you would prefer that it simply disregard.
>
> - One of the ways involves the use of Subversion's runtime configuration system (see the section called “Runtime Configuration Area”), and therefore applies to all the Subversion operations which make use of that runtime configuration, generally those performed on a particular computer, or by a particular user of a computer.
> - The other way makes use of Subversion's directory property support, is more tightly bound to the versioned tree itself, and therefore affects everyone who has a working copy of that tree. Both of the mechanisms use file patterns.
>
> The Subversion runtime configuration system provides an option, **`global-ignores`**, whose value is a whitespace-delimited collection of file patterns (also known as globs).
>   The Subversion client checks these patterns against the names of the files which are candidates for addition to version control, as well as to unversioned files which the svn status command notices.
>   If any file's name matches one of the patterns, Subversion will basically act as if the file didn't exist at all.
>   This is really useful for the kinds of files that you almost never want to version, such as editor backup files like Emacs' `*~` and `.*~` files

Comment: Wow, I wasn't sure if I was going to get an answer on this. Thanks, VonC!